# TCP connect <--> accept with INADDR_LOOPBACK range

Tags: tcp, localhost

I have some production code for a distributed system. Part of this code works by looking up (already established tcp) connections in a hash table, indexed by remote ip address. This code works correctly in a real cluster, with each server running on a unique host.

I am writing a test harness for this code; I initially setup the cluster by having each server run on INADDR_LOOPBACK + a unique port. This works with most of the codebase, except the codepath (i mention above) that looks up connections by ipaddr -- what ends up happening is that the lookup just finds the first connection in the table (since all open conns are to the same ipaddr), and sends a message to an incorrect "server".

I learned that localhost has a range of ips, `127.0.0.0` to `127.255.255.255`. I modified my test setup such that each server is assigned a unique ipaddr from this range. I expected this to function similarly to running a real cluster, if, to each server, its peer is connecting from a different ipaddr.

Sadly, tcp `connect`/`accept` do not have an option to specify this distinction -- i.e., used normally, the server-side call to `accept` a connection always populates the `sockaddr` with INADDR_LOOPBACK (`127.0.0.1`).

Is there a way for `connect` to signal + `accept` to recognize that the connection came from a different ip, though they all map to the same LOOPBACK interface?

Please state in the comments if I can clarify the question. I am unable to share the code for IP reasons.

P.S.: An alternative approach is to plumb the clientside-port into the request, and do the lookup by ip + port. However, this involves modifying the code heavily, which carries risks I'd prefer to avoid. Additionally, the client port is ephemeral, which i expect to cause test flakiness, though I haven't tested this approach. It is my fallback, in case I cannot get the unique-ip approach to work.

Comment: The accept call accepts a connection, initiated from the client to the server. If the client chose 127.0.0.1 as source address, the server can't do anything about it: it's the client's problem (which just has to bind before connect). Your description inverts the cause and the consequence.